# ES6 inheritance: uses `super` to access the properties of the parent class

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Javascript's `super` keyword, when I run the code on Chrome, Babel, TypeScript, I got different results.

My question is which result is correct? And what part of specification defines such behavior?

The following code:

```
class Point {
  getX() {
    console.log(this.x); // C
  }
}

class ColorPoint extends Point {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.x = 2;
    super.x = 3;
    console.log(this.x)   // A
    console.log(super.x)  // B
  }
  
  m() {
    this.getX()
  }
}

const cp = new ColorPoint();
cp.m();
```

The results:

[image]

- Chrome 58.0.3029.110 64bit (V8 5.8.283.38)
- Babel Repl 6.24.2
- TypeScript 2.3

links:

- [gist](https://gist.github.com/justjavac/82494287bb25cd671c781242bce975e1)
- [babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=class%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20getX()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ColorPoint%20extends%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super.x%20%3D%203%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.x)%20%20%20%2F%2F%20A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(super.x)%20%20%2F%2F%20B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20m()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.getX()%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20cp%20%3D%20new%20ColorPoint()%3B%0D%0Acp.m()%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: [from the looks of it super is not intended for properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) Keeping this in mind - i guess - the expected behaviour is the one from babel. Note: i tested this using rollupjs and it matches babel's

Comment: Quite interesting, but what's the question here?

Comment: You're targeting different environments. typescript is targeting es5. If you switch it to es6, it will give the same output as chrome. babel is targeting es2015. Switch that to es2015-loose and you'll get your typescript es5 result.

Comment: Firefox seems to agree with chrome.

Comment: Yes, this is surely a Babel bug, but you shouldn't do this anyway. Assigning or accessing properties on `super` is super weird, it usually falls back to `this`. It's only useful when overwriting getters/setters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short answer:

Chrome is correct. And this is caused by the unbalance between get and set.

[OrdinarySet](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryset) is `reciever` sensitive, but [OrdinaryGet](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryget) is not.

So `super.x = 3` has the same effect of `this.x = 3`, because the receiver here is `this`. Evaluating`super.x`, which never reach `this`, will always get `undefined` because `A.prototype` does not have such field.

---

### More details:

The `super.x` is a [SuperReference](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#super-reference). And assignment to `SuperReference` will call [PutValue(V, W)](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-putvalue), which in turn call `super` object's internal slot [[[Set]]](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver) and finally `OrdinarySet`.

In plain JavaScript, the statement `super.x = 3` is basically equivalent to:

`OrdinarySet(proto, 'x', 3, this)`.

Where `proto` is the super object, internally the [`[[HomeObject]]`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function-environment-records) of constructor `ColorPoint`. `proto` is equivalent to `Object.create(Point.prototype)`, as the [ClassDefinitionEvaluation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation) specifies, and it is passed to constructor as `[[HomeObject]]`.

---

Now let's see how `OrdinarySet` works.  **In step 4c and 4d, the spec requires set operation is done on receiver `this`, not the `proto` object.**

> Let existingDescriptor be ? Receiver.[GetOwnProperty].
>
> If existingDescriptor is not undefined, then
>
> If IsAccessorDescriptor(existingDescriptor) is true, return false.
>
> If existingDescriptor.[[Writable]] is false, return false.
>
> Let valueDesc be the PropertyDescriptor{[[Value]]: V}.
>
> Return ? Receiver.[[DefineOwnProperty]](P, valueDesc).

These statements says `OrdinarySet(proto, 3, this)` means `this.x = 3`.

---

On the other hand, `OrdinaryGet` *ignores* `Receiver` . `super.x` is

`OrdinaryGet(proto, 'x', this)`.

**`OrdinaryGet` does not have `Receiver` in its clauses** at all! So `super.x` is equivalent to `Object.create(Point.prototype).x`, which is `undefined` of course.

As a rule of thumb, if there is discrepancy between transpilers and browsers, browsers, especially Chrome, are usually more loyal to the ECMAScript specification. Transpilers usually trade some edge case correctness for runtime efficiency.

Comment: This case is not a trade off, just a bug of Babel. See: https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/5774

Answer (score 0):

Diffrence I saw :-

`super` helps to take all the this part of above class in it 
 and we can change that this accordingly`

1. we can change this.x of class point by super.x OR this.x in JAVASCRIPT
     But we can can't make change in tyescript with super.x (it will behave 
     the new obect of class colorPoint)..this change can 
     only be happen by this.x
2. we can't make even call 2nd time to super() in JAVASCRIPT it will give an 
     err and we can call the super() in type script 
     it will make re-Initilize the Point constructor class

Typescript thing I have notice in TypeScript [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) by Runing it

```
"use strict";
class Point {

    getX() {
        console.log("POINT " + this.x);
    }
    constructor() {
        this.x = 10;
    }
}

class ColorPoint extends Point {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.y = 2;
        console.log("THIS x" + this.x); //  10
        console.log("THIS y" + this.y); //  2
        console.log("SUPER !" + super.x); //  undef

        super.x = 3;

        console.log("THIS.x after a " + this.x); //  10
        this.x = 20;

        console.log("THIS.x after b " + this.x); //  20

        super();
        console.log("SUPER x" + super.x); // 
        console.log("THIS x" + this.x); // 

        console.log(this); // give this of colorPoint
        console.log(super()); // give this of colorPoint
    }
}

const cp = new ColorPoint();
cp.getX();
```

Javascript thing i have notice in console by command `node super.js`

```
"use strict";
class Point {

    getX() {
        console.log("POINT " + this.x);
    }
    constructor() {
        this.x = 10;
    }
}

class ColorPoint extends Point {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.y = 2;
        console.log("THIS x" + this.x); // 
        console.log("THIS y" + this.y); // 
        // console.log("SUPER" + super.x); // 

        super.x = 3;

        console.log("THIS.x after a " + this.x); // 
        this.x = 20;

        console.log("THIS.x after b " + this.x); // 

        //gives err 
        // super();
        // console.log("SUPER x" + super.x); // 
        // console.log("THIS x" + this.x); // 
    }

    // m() {
    //     this.getX();
    // }
}

const cp = new ColorPoint();
cp.getX();
```

Answer (score -1):

A rule of programming `Garbage in -> Garbage out`. The following code :

```
class Point {
  x: number;
  getX() {
    console.log(this.x);
  }
}

class ColorPoint extends Point {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.x = 2;
    super.x = 3; // ERROR
  }
}
```

You get a nice TypeScript error `Only public and protected methods can be accessed`. Note the word `methods`. `super` should not be used for `properties`. Invalid code is not something you should run.