# In JavaScript Class, super cannot access attributes, but can modify attributes?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

The super attribute cannot be accessed, but can be modified?

What does `super` stand for? Some people say it is prototype? I know that the function of Class is in the prototype of the object, but why can `super.name ='Lucy';` modify the properties of the object instance?

```js
class a {
  name = 'jack';
  speak() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

class b extends a {
  count() {
    super.name = 'Lucy';
    console.log(super.name) // undefined
    super.speak();
  }
}

new b().count(); // Lucy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning to `super.prop` is useful when `prop` is defined on the parent's *prototype*, not when it is defined as an instance property, as is the case with `name` in your code. Realise that the assignment `name = 'jack'` happens on the *instance* that is created by `new b`, not on some other object.

So when you do `super.name = 'Lucy'`, you are doing nothing else than `this.name = 'Lucy'`. This change is not visible when you consult `super.name` after that assignment, because that will scan the parent's prototype chain, *not the instance object*. And there is no `name` defined anywhere on that prototype chain...

The difference between how `super.name` acts when used for *lookup* and for *assignment* is specific: for (non-setter) *assignment*, it is no different than assigning on `this`, while for *lookup* (including setter lookup), it skips `this` and starts the lookup in the parent's prototype chain.

The power of the `super.prop` syntax only reveals itself when you have to deal with methods that have been created *on the prototype*.

To demonstrate this, let's define `name` as a getter/setter function on the prototype:

```js
class A {
  _name = 'jack';
  speak() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  get name() {
      return this._name;
  }
  set name(name) {
      return this._name = name + " (A)";
  }
}

class B extends A {
  count() {
    super.name = 'Lucy'; // This will not call the setter of B.prototype, but of A.prototype
    super.speak();
  }
  get name() {
      return this._name;
  }
  set name(name) {
      return this._name + " (B)";
  }
}

new B().count(); // Lucy (A)
```

Note that here `super.name` is first identified to be a function in the upper prototype chain, and thus the assignment becomes a function call. If it would have been a property-modifying assignment, it would have happened on `this`.

See for an elaborate analysis of the specification in this respect in [this answer to "ES6 inheritance: uses `super` to access the properties of the parent class"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44160500/5459839)

Comment: "*for assignment, it is no different than assigning on `this`*" - your own example disproves that :-)

Comment: @Bergi, I tried to explain that in the text below that example: although the syntax uses `=`, it really resolves to a function call, and so it does not fall under the rule of assignment. A standard (non-setter kind of) assignment will happen on `this`.

Comment: Ah, right. A setter call is still an assignment to me, so I didn't think to make an exception there. To me, `super` always looks up the superclass property, and only if it doesn't find anything, it falls back to a normal property creation/update on the receiver.

Comment: Yes, but it could find a non-setter property in the prototype chain, like a string property (e.g. `A.prototype.name = "test"`), and then still it will assign normally to the `this` property.

Comment: Thanks for telling me this link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44160500/9854149